# ¿Cómo determinar la posición de un número ingresado en Pascal?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Por ejemplo quiero hacer lo siguiente:

```
 Ingrese un número (0 para salir): 18737
 Ingrese el dígito para saber si aparece en 18737: 7
 El dígito 7 aparece por primera vez en la posición 0 y la cantidad de veces que está presente es 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes valerte de las operaciones enteras de división (`div`) y módulo o residuo (`mod`) para *separar* los dígitos de un número.

En el ejemplo a continuación, voy almacenándolos en un arreglo de dígitos, del menos significativo al más significativo. Al final, imprimo la posición en el arreglo y cada uno de los dígitos que componen el número, del más al menos significativo.

Considero que con esto tienes suficiente para poder completar tu ejercicio, pues ya en el arreglo puedes determinar si un dígito es parte del número o no, así como contar cuantas veces ocurre.

```
program so451591;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  Digito = 0..9;
var
  Numero: Integer;
  Digitos: array of Digito;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Numero := 18737;
  while Numero <> 0 do
  begin
    SetLength(Digitos, Length(Digitos) + 1);
    Digitos[high(Digitos)] := Numero mod 10;
    Numero := Numero div 10;
  end;
  for I := High(Digitos) downto Low(Digitos) do
    Writeln(I, ' ', Digitos[I]);
  Readln;
end.
```

La salida de este programa es:

```
4 1
3 8
2 7
1 3
0 7
```

El programa está escrito en Delphi, pero debiera compilar sin problemas en freepascal.